# How does this Github Action modify deployment.yml file

Tags: azure, kubernetes, github-actions, azure-aks

I am using the Azure/k8s-deploy Github Action.
The problem is how do I specify an image in the deployment manifest file so that the action modifies the deployment to a new image URL?

Right now action does not replace the image url.

It tries to apply the file without modifying the image which doesn't work.

```yaml
- uses: azure/k8s-deploy@v1
  with:
    manifests: |
      k8s/deployment.yml
      k8s/service.yml
    images: |
      ${{ env.REGISTRY_NAME }}.azurecr.io/${{ env.APP_NAME }}:${{ github.sha }}
    imagepullsecrets: |
      ${{ env.SECRET }}
    namespace: ${{ env.NAMESPACE }}
```

I want this action to deploy k8s/deployment.yml file with image url given in images field

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be added `Kustomization` step to your `git-action' **but** you will need to create an extra file named` kustomization.yaml` in order to use it.

---

`Kustomization` will allow you to modify the desired image

A sample code on how to update the image with Kustomization:
https://github.com/nirgeier/KubernetesLabs/tree/master/Labs/08-Kustomization#images

---

### `kustomize-github-action`

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/kustomize-github-action

Comment: I used kustomize but then there is another problem. Azure Container Registry requires imagePullSecrets to pull images. Azure/k8s-deploy action handles those pull secrets automatically. Using kustomize i no longer need this action but after that k8s fails to pull images because of 401 unauthorized code which is because of imagePullSecret and i have not found any docs on that as well.